# Extract named items in a list in R

Tags: r, list

In `R`, I have a list generated by the `split()` function, so I have a list where each element is named, and is a data frame.

Is there a quick way to take every named item in the list, and assign it to an object of the same name outside of the list?

So, if I have a list with elements "a", "b", and "c", is there a function I can use to create "a", "b", and "c" as data frames in the global environment outside of the list? I.e. I'd like to automate taking everything out of the list and giving the objects the same name they had in the list.

Example:
I have the list created by the following line of code:

```
my_list <- list("a" = data.frame(1:10, 1:10),
                "b" = data.frame(1:10, 1:10),
                "c" = data.frame(1:10, 1:10))
```

But instead of having `my_list` in the global environment, I want the objects `a`, `b`, and `c` to each be data frames in the global environment that are not inside the list.

Comment: It'll be hard to help you without any concrete example and expected output whatsoever. But perhaps you can look into `list2env`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `list2env` function to assign the elements to objects in the global environment.

```
mylist <- split(1:99,rep(1:3,each=33))
names(mylist) <- c("Element1","Element2","Element3")
list2env(mylist,envir = globalenv())
ls()
[1] "Element1"            "Element2"            "Element3"            "mylist"
```